# $2^{n-1} \prod^{n-1}_{k=1} (\cos \theta-\cos \frac{kπ}{n})= ??$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$$ 2^{n-1} \prod^{n-1}_{k=1} (\cos \theta-\cos \frac{kπ}{n})= ?? $$

In this question I thought that in some way or the other complex numbers should be involved along with roots of unity, but actually I could not resolve it into any equation. I thought of forming an equation like $\prod^{n-1}_{k=1} (x-\cos \frac{kπ}{n})$, but because only real part of the n th root of unity was involved I couldn't solve further. Help me please.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question.

Comment: @StefanLafon  I just copied the text of the mathjax... Oh sorry, my mistake, a k slipped in , so sorry

Comment: Seems like you fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$\cos(\frac {k\pi} n)$ for $k=1...n-1$ are the [roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Roots_and_extrema) of $U_{n-1}$, the [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition) of degree $n-1$.

The leading coefficient of $U_{n-1}$ is $2^{n-1}$. Therefore that polynomial can be written as 
$$U_{n-1}(X)=2^{n-1} \prod^{n-1}_{k=1} \left (X-\cos \frac{kπ}{n}\right)$$
Evaluating at $X=\cos\theta$ shows that the expression you're looking for is $U_{n-1}(\cos \theta)$.

Using a famous identity for that polynomial leads to
$$2^{n-1} \prod^{n-1}_{k=1} (\cos \theta-\cos \frac{kπ}{n})= \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin \theta}$$